# Should you clean up your DB after integration tests?

Tags: database, integration-tests, integration-testing

Is it good practice to clean up your DB after running integration tests (which tests APIs that put data into that DB)? I want to have a cleanup method after my integration tests run which will access the DB through a data access layer but is this recommended?

Answer (score 11):

You need to do it *before* every test, obviously, in order for the test not to be affected by other tests.

On the other hand, keep the data in the database *after* the test **in order to make it easier to debug a test, especially the one which fails**.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't write tests that do cleanup afterwards, for multiple reasons:

1. None of the major test frameworks provide a general solution for cleanup after tests.  Junit and Cucumber have after-test hooks, but people generally don't use them.   Do a Google search, and you'll find people generally do not recommend it.
2. Don't do after-test cleanup unless you have to.   In my experience, 99% of the time, a BeforeTest setup works for cleaning up data.
3. If you do cleanup after tests, make sure that your tests still work in multi-threaded mode.   Often times, cleanup after tests might cause other test to fail when tests are ran in multi-threaded mode.
4. "Data testers" tend to have a "cleanup afterwards attitude" that is a side-effect of architectural decisions making the database not very testable without causing problems.   Resetting the TEST database back to a known state, such as once per quarter, might resolve these concerns?

Comment: those aren't reasons